# JavaScript regular expression help: Lines in a text string beginning with "On such-and-such a date some other stuff wrote:"

Tags: javascript, regex

In received email, the first line is of the form:

> ** New update from 'Doug, Mon And Monta - Test Group': reply above this line to comment **

When somebody replies, on the server side I'm able to strip out those incoming lines with a simple `indexOf()` check.

The problem is that some mail clients (such as my own Apple Mail) add additional text above that line when replying of the form:

> On Dec 28, 2012, at 10:19 AM, "XYZ Communities - Doug, Mon And Monta -
>   Test Group" wrote:

I tried trapping that with a regular expression like this:

```
var rx1 = new RegExp('on.*wrote:', 'ig');
```

While this works in most cases, it unfortunately also catches cases where a person might reply with text containing "on" earlier on, such as:

> At that site, I think what we are interested in is the AgroTagger
>   service described on this page where...

Under certain circumstances the "on" in the above text is found and everything after that gets trimmed by my code.

I tried to narrow the scope of the regular expression by including the begin-of-line character and adding the multiline modifier like this:

```
var rx1 = new RegExp('^on.*wrote:', 'igm');
```

But in that case the line is not found at all and is included with the text. I guess the ^ metacharacter for beginning of a line doesn't really work for a line in the middle of a JavaScript string?

Anyway, any suggestions would be appreciated. Basically, I'm trimming out the "reply above" line ok using a few variations of `indexOf()`. What I need is an extra check after that for the case where a mail client adds more unneeded text above that line.

Thanks,

doug

p.s. If anybody can tell me how I can receive email notifications when replies are posted here I would be very greatful. Nothing I've tried works so far.

Comment: You don't really describe how you want it to work when they put text above the precanned line.  Do you just want to strip everything before your precanned line regardless of what it is?

Comment: I would like to strip everything starting with the precanned line, leaving everything above it. 

In the case where just the "reply above" line is there I trim from that point onwards. So in the case where a mail client adds extra text above that, such as "On such-and-such a date somebody wrote:" I would like to trim from there on as well - just leaving the actual reply above.

Comment: I'm not sure how to neatly enter code here, but to clarify, once I find a match of the position of the regular expression of the text I'm trimming like this:

var rx1 = new RegExp('^on.*wrote:', 'igm');
  var rx1Idx = location.nodeValue.search(rx1);
  if (rx1Idx != -1) {
   location.nodeValue = location.nodeValue.substring(0, rx1Idx);
  }

Comment: There is no precise algorithm for stripping from "on such and such a date somebody wrote:" because there is no standard for how that text will be formatted or what it will say.  If they don't follow the desired format, you are guessing where to cut.

Comment: I agree with @jfriend00.  Different email clients will format replies differently.  Some (Thunderbird) can even be configured to place the quoted content at the top and the new content at the bottom.

Comment: In the particular case the line always begins with "On" and ends with "wrote:". And the line can fall in the middle of the string. Is there some way I can deal with that? If I run into problems with other clients I can tackle them as special cases. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your email notification question, I think you should be able to turn this on in your user preferences page (click user name, click "prefs"), but I think the emails are only weekly: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/now-showing-email-notifications/

Comment: The `m` modifier of the regex should make `^` match newlines in the middle of the string. I just tried `"foo\non Monday so-and-so wrote:".search(rx1)` and it returned 4. I suggest you check the data to see if `On` is actually at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @DougLerner: you say that `the line always begins with "On" and ends with "wrote:".`. This is true _if and only if the mail client is configured to use an English locale_.

Comment: @fge - Yes, that's true. But for now I'd like to get that working and then generalize it later on.

Comment: I was looking more into this and the problem may be simpler than I thought. Apple isn't sending a newline for the line starting with "On...". It's starting that line with a <div>On!

Comment: Yes, that was it. I feel so stupid. For the longest time I was obsessed with the part that was getting truncated off too soon that I neglected to properly log what was being ignored. I changed my regular expression to `var rx1 = new RegExp('\<div\>on.*wrote:', 'ig');` and it works fine now (for this case). I greatly appreciate everybody's assistance. There was no single correct answer, so I'm not sure how to mark this thread.

Answer (score 1):

For the text you describe, this is working in my tests...

```
emailBody = emailBody.replace(new RegExp("^On .+ wrote:$[.\\r\\n]*", "im"), "");
```

... which is very much like your regex - so I'm not sure why your's did not match at all.

I did notice in some of the emails in my inbox that there is whitespace at the beginnings of the lines.  Perhaps this is the problem you're having?  In that case, this would fix it:

```
emailBody = emailBody.replace(new RegExp("^\\s*On .+ wrote:\\s*$[.\\r\\n]*", "im"), "");
```

Comment: Daniel, in your expression, why do you have the $ and also the [.\\r\\n] part?

Comment: I just tried your latter version: var rx1 = new RegExp("^\\s*On .+ wrote:\\s*$[.\\r\\n]*", "im"); but that didn't catch the line either. I remember reading elsewhere that ^ and $ don't work in the middle of JavaScript strings and they really represent "beginning of the string" and "end of the string". Could that be what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: In multi-line mode (m), `^` and `$` will match the beginning and ends of lines, not just the beginning and end of the string.  The special thing about JavaScript is that there is no option to make `.` match newline characters.  Here is the regex website I usually us as a reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: I have the `$` in my expression because you said that "wrote:" is always at the end of the line.  The `[.\r\n]*` should match every line after the magic line you're looking for.  That way, you should be able to simply replace what was matched with the empty string to delete it.